# Is $P(G,x)= (x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1)$ a sufficient condition to G is an n-cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

The way to prove the chromatic polynomial of a n-cycle graph G is $P(G,x)= (x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1)$ is well known. While, I find it not so easy to prove another direction.

The connectivity of G is the first problem I met. I try to solve it by factoring. $P(G,x)=(x-1)\left[(x-1)^n+(-1)^n\right]$. Intuitively, It might work. However, I have no idea to explain it in plain words.

Then, I don't know what to do to solve the rest problem as well. The only clue I can get is when $x=3, P(G,x)>0 \Rightarrow 3=\chi(G)\ge\omega(G)$.

Any hint or idea would be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

QAQ I figure out a possible solution.
[image]

Above theorems can be easily proved by Birkhoff-Lewis reduction thereom $c_G(k)=c_{G-e}(k) - c_{G/e}(k)$.

Based on above thereoms, this question would be much easier! o(≧v≦)o

Firstly, $G$ is connected. This can be induct from #3, since if $G$ is disconnected $c_G(k)$ would equal to the product of its component and the coefficient of x would be $0$.

Then, $G$ can not be tree because $P(T,x)=x(x-1)^{n-1}$ for a tree T. Therefore, there should be at least one cycle in G. By #5 of above theorem, there is $n$ edges in $G$, so there can only be one cycle.

At last, to prove $G$ is the cycle itself, instead of a cycle attached with some edges. Supposing G contain the cycle $C$ and $|C|=k\le n$. Then $P(G,x)$ should be $[(k-1)^k+(-1)^k(x-1)](x-1)^{n-k}$ which equals to $(x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1)$ only when $k=n$.

Q.E.D.  (o゜▽゜)o☆[BINGO!]

update: fix tons of grammatical error(I'm not a native English speaker...)